# Apply rotation defined by Euler angles to 3D image, in python

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, image-rotation, euler-angles

I'm working with 3D images and have to rotate them according to Euler angles (phi,psi,theta) in 'zxz' convention (these Euler angles are part of a dataset, so I have to use that convention). I found the function scipy.ndimage.rotate that seems useful in that regard.

```
arrayR = scipy.ndimage.rotate(array , phi, axes=(0,1), reshape=False)
arrayR = scipy.ndimage.rotate(arrayR, psi, axes=(1,2), reshape=False)
arrayR = scipy.ndimage.rotate(arrayR, the, axes=(0,1), reshape=False)
```

Sadly, this does not do what intended. This is why:

Definition:

> In the z-x-z convention, the x-y-z frame is rotated three times: first
>   about the z-axis by an angle phi; then about the **new** x-axis by an
>   angle psi; then about the **newest** z-axis by an angle theta.

However with above code, the rotations are always with respect to the original axes. Which is why obtained rotations are not correct. Anyone has a suggestion to obtain correct rotations, as explained in the definition?

In other words, in the present 'zxz' convention the rotations are intrinsic (rotations about the axes of the rotating coordinate system XYZ, solidary with the moving body, which changes its orientation after each elemental rotation). If I use the above code, the rotations are extrinsic (rotations about the axes xyz of the original coordinate system, which is assumed to remain motionless). I need a way for doing extrinsic rotations, in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a satisfying solution following this link: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/f05ee20b5a826e4c8b9bb3e528348688

This method uses np.meshgrid, scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates. The above link uses some third party library for generating the rotation matrix, however I use scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation. This function allows to define both intrinsic and extrinsic rotations: see description of scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.

Here is my function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates

# Rotates 3D image around image center
# INPUTS
#   array: 3D numpy array
#   orient: list of Euler angles (phi,psi,the)
# OUTPUT
#   arrayR: rotated 3D numpy array
# by E. Moebel, 2020
def rotate_array(array, orient):
    phi = orient[0]
    psi = orient[1]
    the = orient[2]

    # create meshgrid
    dim = array.shape
    ax = np.arange(dim[0])
    ay = np.arange(dim[1])
    az = np.arange(dim[2])
    coords = np.meshgrid(ax, ay, az)

    # stack the meshgrid to position vectors, center them around 0 by substracting dim/2
    xyz = np.vstack([coords[0].reshape(-1) - float(dim[0]) / 2,  # x coordinate, centered
                     coords[1].reshape(-1) - float(dim[1]) / 2,  # y coordinate, centered
                     coords[2].reshape(-1) - float(dim[2]) / 2])  # z coordinate, centered

    # create transformation matrix
    r = R.from_euler('zxz', [phi, psi, the], degrees=True)
    mat = r.as_matrix()

    # apply transformation
    transformed_xyz = np.dot(mat, xyz)

    # extract coordinates
    x = transformed_xyz[0, :] + float(dim[0]) / 2
    y = transformed_xyz[1, :] + float(dim[1]) / 2
    z = transformed_xyz[2, :] + float(dim[2]) / 2

    x = x.reshape((dim[1],dim[0],dim[2]))
    y = y.reshape((dim[1],dim[0],dim[2]))
    z = z.reshape((dim[1],dim[0],dim[2])) # reason for strange ordering: see next line

    # the coordinate system seems to be strange, it has to be ordered like this
    new_xyz = [y, x, z]

    # sample
    arrayR = map_coordinates(array, new_xyz, order=1)
```

Note:
You can also use this function for intrinsic rotations, simply adapt the first argument of 'from_euler' to your Euler convention. In this case, you obtain equivalent result than in my 1st post (using scipy.ndimage.rotate). However I noticed that the present code is 3x faster (0.01s for 40^3 volume) than when using scipy.ndimage.rotate (0.03s for 40^3 volume).

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a bit confusion about the "axes" parameter in your **first** post.  To do a rotation about the x axis, the plane of rotation would be the yz plane which means your "axes" parameter should be set to (1,2).  Also the first and the third rotations are, presumably about the x and z axes.  But, both your rotations are in the xy plane.  Could these be possibly the reasons behind the discrepancies in your answers?  I am not convinced by your explanations about the new and original axes.  The independent calls to the "rotate" function does not have access to the old data in any form or shape.  It only sees the new axes and rotated array.

Answer (score 0):

I check the code https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/f05ee20b5a826e4c8b9bb3e528348688
There is a minor bug. The tested image is square, but if doing rectangular image, it will encounter some problems. below are correct ones for 2D and 3D rotations (noted that the Euler angle sequence used in my example is 'ZYZ', you should define this before using it):

def rotate_array_2D(array, orient):

```
# create a transformation matrix
angle=orient/180.*np.pi
c=np.cos(angle)
s=np.sin(angle)
mat=np.array([[c,s],[-s,c]])


# create meshgrid
dim = array.shape
ax = np.arange(dim[0])
ay = np.arange(dim[1])

coords = np.meshgrid(ax, ay)

# stack the meshgrid to position vectors, center them around 0 by substracting dim/2
xy = np.vstack([coords[0].reshape(-1) - float(dim[0]) / 2,  # x coordinate, centered
                 coords[1].reshape(-1) - float(dim[1]) / 2])  # y coordinate, centered  



# apply transformation
transformed_xy = np.dot(mat, xy)

# extract coordinates
x = transformed_xy[0, :] + float(dim[0]) / 2
y = transformed_xy[1, :] + float(dim[1]) / 2


x = x.reshape((dim[1],dim[0]))
y = y.reshape((dim[1],dim[0]))
new_xy = [x,y]

# sample
arrayR = map_coordinates(array, new_xy, order=1).T
return arrayR
```

def rotate_array_3D(array, orient):

```
rot = orient[0]
tilt = orient[1]
phi = orient[2]

# create meshgrid
dim = array.shape
ax = np.arange(dim[0])
ay = np.arange(dim[1])
az = np.arange(dim[2])
coords = np.meshgrid(ax, ay, az)

# stack the meshgrid to position vectors, center them around 0 by substracting dim/2
xyz = np.vstack([coords[0].reshape(-1) - float(dim[0]) / 2,  # x coordinate, centered
                 coords[1].reshape(-1) - float(dim[1]) / 2,  # y coordinate, centered
                 coords[2].reshape(-1) - float(dim[2]) / 2])  # z coordinate, centered

# create transformation matrix
r = R.from_euler('ZYZ', [rot, tilt, phi], degrees=True)
mat = r.as_matrix()

# apply transformation
transformed_xyz = np.dot(mat, xyz)

# extract coordinates
x = transformed_xyz[0, :] + float(dim[0]) / 2
y = transformed_xyz[1, :] + float(dim[1]) / 2
z = transformed_xyz[2, :] + float(dim[2]) / 2

x = x.reshape((dim[1],dim[0],dim[2]))
y = y.reshape((dim[1],dim[0],dim[2]))
z = z.reshape((dim[1],dim[0],dim[2])) # I test the rotation in 2D and this strange thing can be explained
new_xyz = [x,y,z]

arrayR = map_coordinates(array, new_xyz, order=1).T
return arrayR
```